# Docker: preventing multiple docker images overwriting /usr/local/bin?

Tags: docker

Dockerfile One

```
FROM ubuntu
FROM docker

CMD ["ls", "/usr/local/bin"]
```

Then,

```
docker build -t test .
docker run test
```

Output:

```
docker
docker-containerd
docker-containerd-ctr
docker-containerd-shim
docker-entrypoint.sh
docker-init
docker-proxy
docker-runc
dockerd
modprobe
```

Added python image as below

Dockerfile Two

```
FROM ubuntu
FROM docker
FROM python:2.7-slim

CMD ["ls", "/usr/local/bin"]
```

Then,

```
docker build -t test .
docker run test
```

Output

```
2to3
easy_install
easy_install-2.7
idle
pip
pip2
pip2.7
pydoc
python
python-config
python2
python2-config
python2.7
python2.7-config
smtpd.py
wheel
```

Where did docker binaries go in the second test image?
How can i have both python and docker installed i.e. both python and docker executables in /usr/local/bin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are using docker multi stage builds. This means that your resulting image would only consist of the last `FROM` onwards. For this same reason you don't have the `ubuntu` contents in the `docker` image layer.

You need to `COPY` the binaries from the previous layer:

```
FROM ubuntu
FROM docker as docker
FROM python:2.7-slim
COPY --from=docker /usr/local/bin/* /usr/local/bin/
CMD ["ls", "/usr/local/bin"]
```

Note that you can also reference the previous images by index and `as` is optional:

```
COPY --from=1 /usr/local/bin/* /usr/local/bin/
```

---

Dockerfile COPY reference [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy)

Multi stage builds docs [here](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/)

Comment: thank you that worked showing the binaries. when i invoked python so it errored out. i think i need to copy more than just whats in /usr/local/bin